# Where do we need to pass the value for System.getProperty in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have imported an existing Java EE application into my Eclipse IDE.

I found this piece of code under it

```
public static String decideEnv() {
        String env = null;
        env = (String) System.getProperties().get("TB_ENVIRONEMNT");
            return env;
    }
```

could anybody please let me know from where exactly it gets the value with this line

```
System.getProperties().get("TB_ENVIRONEMNT")
```

Do we need to set this value anywhere ??

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-detect-os-in-java-systemgetpropertyosname/

Answer (score 13):

Go to Run/Run Configurations, locate your run configuration (I guess you are using applicaiton server), choose it and add `-DTB_ENVIRONEMNT=your value here` to Arguments tab, text area "VM arguments"

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple ways to set the system properties, following ways are common

1. search in your code if it sets programatically (do file search )
2. When it loads the app to server, we can pass the system properties there too
3. Also see in your native OS's system properties

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it from command line using `-Dname=value` switch:

```
java my-app -DTB_ENVIRONEMNT=dev
```